# Ruby ON rails- Webrick

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting the following error while giving the "rails s" command in my cmd. the error is given in the link.
i am using mongodb as my database and not mysql.'pls suggest what to do

http://paste.kde.org/742976

-- Relevant Clip ---

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.13 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': Please install the sqlite3 adapter: `gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter` (cannot load such file --sqlite3/sqlite3_native) (LoadError)
```

Comment: Can you paste your Gemfile?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a ODM like `Mongoid` you will need to get rid of `ActiveRecord` in order to use MongoDB properly.

Instructions here should be helpful: http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html

```
Open myapp/config/application.rb and near the top, remove the line require "rails/all"
```

Comment: That is not true at all. I use mongoid ans MySQL+ postgres with AR all in one app.

Comment: @cpuguy83 I'm not saying you cannot use them all together. OP is asking how to solve this error message while using MongoDB and NOT MySQL or the like - this is just one suggestion.